# Resize all PDF pages to letter size - how to resize or remove CropBox?

Tags: ghostscript

I'm using a service that requires all PDF pages to be the same exact size. Right now, the second page of my PDF is US letter size, but the first page is a little smaller than that - I would like the first page to be letter size as well.

[Here's a sample PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8zekoj96gxhex3/input.pdf?dl=0) of what I'm starting with. Here's what `pdfinfo` says about this file to start with:

```
Creator:        pdftk 2.02 - www.pdftk.com
Producer:       itext-paulo-155 (itextpdf.sf.net-lowagie.com)
CreationDate:   Fri Jun  5 11:37:13 2020 CDT
ModDate:        Fri Jun  5 11:37:13 2020 CDT
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           AcroForm
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          2
Encrypted:      no
Page    1 size: 576 x 755.999 pts
Page    1 rot:  0
Page    2 size: 612 x 792 pts (letter)
Page    2 rot:  0
Page    1 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   576.00   756.00
Page    1 CropBox:      0.00     0.00   576.00   756.00
Page    1 BleedBox:     0.00     0.00   576.00   756.00
Page    1 TrimBox:      0.00     0.00   576.00   756.00
Page    1 ArtBox:      44.83   151.48   534.17   576.50
Page    2 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    2 CropBox:      0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    2 BleedBox:     0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    2 TrimBox:      0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    2 ArtBox:       0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
File size:      484669 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.
```

My first attempt looked like this:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q \
  -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/tmp/output.pdf \
  /tmp/input.pdf
```

Here's what `pdfinfo` says about the output from this:

```
Creator:        pdftk 2.02 - www.pdftk.com
Producer:       GPL Ghostscript 9.26
CreationDate:   Fri Jun  5 11:46:15 2020 CDT
ModDate:        Fri Jun  5 11:46:15 2020 CDT
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          2
Encrypted:      no
Page    1 size: 603.429 x 792 pts
Page    1 rot:  0
Page    2 size: 612 x 792 pts (letter)
Page    2 rot:  0
Page    1 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    1 CropBox:      4.29     0.00   607.71   792.00
Page    1 BleedBox:     4.29     0.00   607.71   792.00
Page    1 TrimBox:      4.29     0.00   607.71   792.00
Page    1 ArtBox:      51.25   158.69   563.89   603.95
Page    2 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    2 CropBox:      0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    2 BleedBox:     0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    2 TrimBox:      0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    2 ArtBox:       0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
File size:      143412 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.7
```

At this point the service I'm using is still rejecting my PDF for mis-matched page sizes, I'm guessing because page 1 of the PDF has a CropBox set.

At this point I tried to set the CropBox to the same dimensions as the MediaBox using this command:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q \
  -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/tmp/output.pdf \
  -c "[/CropBox [0 0 612 792] /PAGES pdfmark" \
  -f /tmp/input.pdf
```

But it doesn't seem to be having any effect - the `pdfinfo` is still identical, except for the file size being slightly larger at `143435 bytes`.

How do I resize or remove the CropBox of my PDF to get everything to render at the MediaBox page size?

This is my Ghostscript version:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.26 (2018-11-20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6457353/215168) that includes a method to remove CropBoxes using `sed` (!), which seems to be working for me:

```
sed -i.bak -e "/CropBox/,/]/s#.# #g" /tmp/output.pdf
```

`pdfinfo`:

```
Creator:        pdftk 2.02 - www.pdftk.com
Producer:       GPL Ghostscript 9.26
CreationDate:   Fri Jun  5 12:03:07 2020 CDT
ModDate:        Fri Jun  5 12:03:07 2020 CDT
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          2
Encrypted:      no
Page    1 size: 612 x 792 pts (letter)
Page    1 rot:  0
Page    2 size: 612 x 792 pts (letter)
Page    2 rot:  0
Page    1 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    1 CropBox:      0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    1 BleedBox:     0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    1 TrimBox:      4.29     0.00   607.71   792.00
Page    1 ArtBox:      51.25   158.69   563.89   603.95
Page    2 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    2 CropBox:      0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    2 BleedBox:     0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    2 TrimBox:      0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
Page    2 ArtBox:       0.00     0.00   612.00   792.00
File size:      143413 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.7
```

Hopefully there's a better way to do this in Ghostscript rather than mutilating the file through direct text editing, but for now it's working and the service I'm using is now accepting the file.